# Angular ':increment' / ':decrement' aliases not triggering

Tags: angular, animation, aliases

I am having bit of an issue with Angular animations. The goal is to create 'swipe' effect when entering hidden sibling menus.

Currently, the menu structure is flat due to the design I need to achieve. This means even submenus are on level of siblings with their actual parents. The menus are triggered based on property as ID.

I was able to apply Angular animations to this process, showing 'swipe' effect from **left to right**. The problem is when I go back. If I go to submenu, I need to be able to go 'up' to parent. In this case, the animation should be reversed - from **right to left**.

I tried achieving this by setting menuActiveState property and listening for :increment and :decrement in the animation. However, Angular doesn't seem to listen to it at all as no animation runs whatsoever and I am not really sure why.

Activating menu and adjusting increment / decrement

```
menuActiveState: number = 0;

activate(id,direction) {

  if(direction == 1) {
    this.menuActiveState++;
  } else {
    this.menuActiveState--;
  }

  this.menuActive = id;

}
```

Binding on menu element

```
<ul class="list" [@menuActivateSubmenu]="menuActiveState" *ngIf="ismenuvisible('1')">
  ...
</ul>
<ul class="list" [@menuActivateSubmenu]="menuActiveState" *ngIf="ismenuvisible('1-1')">
  ...
</ul>
```

Actual animation:

```
trigger('menuActivateSubmenu', [
  transition(':increment', group([
    query(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', zIndex: 2, position: 'relative'}),
      animate('350ms ease', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
    ]),
    query(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute'}),
      animate('350ms ease', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ], { optional: true })
  ])),
  transition(':decrement', group([
    query(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', zIndex: 2, position: 'relative'}),
      animate('350ms ease', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
    ]),
    query(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute'}),
      animate('350ms ease', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
    ], { optional: true })
  ]))
])
```

I created a StackBlitz project with current implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-menu-swipe

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have fixed it - the solution was to move the trigger one level up to the  wrapping all the menus.

For anyone still looking for answer to this problem, I updated the StackBlitz sample